# jCrop creates a black image instead of new image

Tags: php, jquery, jcrop

i'm trying with this code.

```
<?php 
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
       $src=$_POST['src'];
       $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
       $jpeg_quality = 90;
       $output_filename=$src;
       $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
       $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);  
       imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
       $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
       imagejpeg($dst_r, $output_filename, $jpeg_quality);
   }
?>
```

Please someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you do `print_r($_POST);` and see what does that give you?

Comment: does this only happen when you try to create an jpg from an png file?

Comment: How i can crop an png or bmp image using jcrop?